# Integrating a Back button

Tags: html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have this theme http://themes.two2twelve.com/site/fluidapp/light/ installed on my website running wordpress. I converted the template to a wordpress theme by following the steps here: http://thethemefoundry.com/blog/html-wordpress/ and its all working fine.

However, I have now been given the crazy task to integrate a "Back button" function in it. 
What they want is to have some sort of Back button functionality (or the browser one) so when they open **Team** and they press Back - they go back to **Home**. The template is basically one-paged, you can see so in the source code.

One way I can see this happening is if I make every page a different .php file, upload them to my theme folder and then just hyperlink them. like www.yoursite.com/team.php

Another possible way (I think) would be to create a page.php template file and then post the pages using wordpress. **Question:** How do I tell wordpress to use page.php as the page template file?

Can you think of another way to integrate this functionality? Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If it always is going to return the user to the startpage you could just use the home_url(); function.

```
<a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>">Back</a>
```

If you got more advance structure and you want the button to just redirect the user back one page, you should use javascript.

```
<a href="javascript:history.go(-1)">Back</a>
```

page.php is the default template for wordpress pages. So if no other is selected in admin, page.php will be used.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using javascript to load the new content, you could use javascript `pushState()`and `popState()` to log the stuff to new url's, and it gets added to the browser history. [Here's an example.](http://html5.gingerhost.com/)